# The name of the file that cannot be opened

Tags: go, logging

I receive error logs like this:

> 2023/12/27 04:11:26 open : The system cannot find the file specified.

I have lots of function calls like:

```golang
    pth := "..."

    data, err := os.ReadFile(pth)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
    }
```

## Easier debugging

I want to modify the error logs so that they write the exact name of the file that couldn't be opened. Is there an automatic way to force the logs to do that?

Comment: The error message already contains the file name, it's the empty string in your case. `os.ReadFile("foo")` will return an error: `open foo: no such file or directory`

Comment: Also note that `log.Fatalf()` is OK for testing, but in production you'd rarely want to use that as it terminates your app.

Comment: FWIW, you could read [the docs on `os.Open`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Open) and notice they read: „If there is an error, it will be of type `*PathError`.” Reading the docs on that error type, in turn, would tell you the type contains a field `Path` containing the pathname of the failing entity. Knowing that, you could then [type-assert](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) the returned error and inspect that field programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @icza :

> The error message already contains the file name, it's the empty string in your case.

In my case:

> 2023/12/27 04:11:26 open {EMPTY STRING}: The system cannot find the file specified.